# Notification control isn't working for 'react-native-track-player'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native application i'm using `react-native-track-player`. Everything is working well but i can't control music from the notification panel. Here's the versions which i'm using:

React Native: `"0.63.4"`

react-native-track-player: `"^2.1.2"`

And here's my code for the capability part:

```js
const updateTrackPlayerOptions = async () => {
  return await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
    jumpInterval: 5,
    alwaysPauseOnInterruption: true,
    stopWithApp: false,
    capabilities: [
      Capability.Play,
      Capability.Pause,
      Capability.Stop,
      Capability.SkipToNext,
      Capability.SkipToPrevious,
      Capability.SeekTo,
    ],
    compactCapabilities: [
      Capability.Play,
      Capability.Pause,
      Capability.Stop,
      Capability.SkipToNext,
      Capability.SkipToPrevious,
      Capability.SeekTo,
    ],
    notificationCapabilities: [
      Capability.Play,
      Capability.Pause,
      Capability.SkipToNext,
      Capability.SkipToPrevious,
    ],
  })
}
```

Seems like no event is fired when i press pause or play from the notification panel. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this problem yet ? Please share your answer if you've found one. Thanks

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet @AliRaza

Answer (score 0):

in your playbackService.js instead of:
TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePlay, ()=>{})
use:
TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', ()=>{})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).